# marquee text in HTML select

Tags: javascript, html, html-select, marquee

I have an HTML select menu with the options inside coming in from a dynamic list. What I want is that if the length of the option is greater than the select box, the option text should move to right like in marquee but stop as soon as the end of text is encountered.

I am trying this with a marquee inside the select box but am not able to get the result.

Please advice!

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far

Comment: i am using mustache framework and dynamically generating the select menu. The mustache template I am using to generate the options list is like                                                           '{{#select}}<option id="{{id}}" value="{{value}}" {{#selected}}selected{{/selected}} ><marquee>{{text}}</marquee></option>{{/select}}'

Comment: <select id="test" style="width:100px;">
    <option value="1"><marquee loop="40">#1 Long option value to be truncated</marquee></option>
    <option value="2"><marquee loop="40">#2 Long option value to be truncated</marquee></option>
    <option value="3"><marquee loop="40">#3 Long option value to be truncated</marquee></option>
    <option value="4"><marquee loop="40">#4 Long option value to be truncated</marquee></option>
</select>

Comment: That's definitely not going to work. Even if it did, it would 1) look weird and 2) not be very usable (because part of it would be hidden). You could consider a custom JavaScript dropdown list which would give you more flexibility (e.g. the ability to scroll left/right).